# Fastest deskew algorithm?

Tags: c++, algorithm, image-processing, twain

I am a little overwhelmed by my task at hand. We have a toolkit which we use for TWAIN scanning. Some of our customers are complaining about slower scan speeds when the deskew option is set. This is because if their scanner does not support a hardware deskew, it is done in post-processing on the CPU. I was wondering if anyone knows of a good (i.e. fast) algorithm to achieve this. It is hard for me to say what algorithm we are using now. What algorithms are out there for this, and how do they rank as far as speed/accuracy? If I knew the names of the algorithms, it could be easier for me to do a google search on them.

Thank You.
-Tom

Comment: "Image deskew algorithm".  Buy: http://www.leadtools.com/help/leadtools/v15/DocumentImaging/default.htm?turl=WordDocuments%2Fdocumentcleanupkeyfeatures1.htm

Comment: in c++ http://www.sydlogan.com/deskew.html

Comment: Can you post an sample image(s) typical of what you want to deskew and I can measure the time it takes and oist back the resulting image(s).  A 300dpi G4 TIFF image should take less than a second on today's hardware including decompression and compression.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you scanning in Color or B/W ?

Deskew is processor intensive.  A Group4 tiff or JPEG must be decompressed, skew angle determined, deskewed and then compressed.

There are many image processing algorithms out there with deskew and I have evaluated many over the years.  There are some huge differences in processing speed between the different libraries and a lot of it comes down to how well it is coded rather than the algorithm used.  There is a huge difference in commercial libraries just reading and writing images.

The fastest commerical deskew I have used by far comes from Unisoft Imaging (www.unisoftimaging.com).  I assume much of it is written in assembler.  Unisoft has been around for many years and is very fast and efficient.  It supports different many different deskew options including black border removal, color and B/W deskew.  The Group4 routines are very solid and very fast.  The library comes with many other image processing options as well as TWAIN and native SCSI scanner support.  It also supports Unix.

If you want a free deskew then you might want to have a look at Leptonica.  It does not come with too much documentation but is very stable and well written.  http://www.leptonica.com/

Developing code from scratch could be quite time consuming and may be quite buggy and prone to errors.

The other option is to process the document in a separate process so that scanning can run at the speed of the scanner.  At the moment you are probably processing everything in a parallel fashion, one task after another, hence the slowdown.

Comment: +1 for leptonica (leptonlib).  It uses libtiff for decoding/encoding, which is reasonably fast, and the deskew algorithm is one of the fastest ones I've seen (differential line sums for angle detection, and rasterop shearing for rotation). And I disagree about the documentation - the source files have pretty good documentation comments, there's just no "all in one place" documentation. It would be an excellent choice, considering you're developing in C++.

Comment: I am just getting into Leptonica myself.  I just looked into the source code and have to agree with you.  The source code comments are very helpful.  It would be nice to have it in one place though.  Lpetonica is well supported and is now an integral part of the Google Tesseract OCR project.

Comment: +1 again for leptonlib, I am using it in my application for JBig2... however how I really solved this - reduced the min and max angles it projects. I got it down to half a second, which is acceptable

Answer (score 0):

Consider doing it as post-processing, because deskew cannot be done at real-time (unless it's hardware accelerated).

Deskew consists of two steps: skew detection and rotation. Detecting the skew angle can usually be done on a B&W (1-bit) image faster. Rotation speed depends on the quality of the interpolation. A good quality deskew will take a lot of time to run, much more than scanning pages.

A good high speed scanner can do 120 double-sided pages per minute, if it has hardware JPEG or TIFF Group 4 compression, and your TWAIN library takes advantage of it (hint: do not use native mode). You barely have enough time to save the file to the hard drive at that speed, let alone decompress, skew detect, rotate, re-compress. Quality deskew takes several seconds per page, unless you can use the video card's hardware accelerator to rotate and compress.

Answer (score 0):

Do I correctly understand you already have such algorithm implemented? If so, are you sure there is no space for optimization? I'd start with profiling existing solution.

Anyway, I guess you should look for fast digital Radon transform algorithm.

Take a look at http://pagetools.sourceforge.net. They have deskew algorithm implementation.